# How to set Manifest's attributes in Gradle 8.x and Kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-dsl

Recently I created a project in Kotlin that used Kotlin DSL for the `build.gradle.kts` file and I used Gradle **7.4.2** but after upgrading to **8.0.2** I'm unable to set attributes for manifest. I did that to set the main class for creating the jar file.
A portion of my `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "io.github.yamin8000.twitterscrapper.MainKt"
    }
    configurations["compileClasspath"].forEach { file: File ->
        from(zipTree(file.absoluteFile))
    }
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
}
```

IDE complains that `No set method providing array access` for line 3.
So what's the alternative to array access which looks unavailable in Gradle 8.x.?

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question but maybe this could help someone.

`manifest.attributes` is an object of type `Attributes`. What you should do is:

```
manifest {
    attributes("Main-Class" to "io.github.yamin8000.twitterscrapper.MainKt")
}
```